# How can I see CPU usage from my own SQL queries?

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm using Teradata Studio 16.10 and trying to optimize a query that I've been using (actually, more specifically, my IT department is emailing me asking why I am using so many CPU cycles on their database). Is there an easy way for me to see how many CPU cycles my query is consuming, so I can better optimize it? Or is DBMS time a good proxy for CPU cycle usage?

In the SQL History window, it shows "Fetch Time" and "DBMS Time", but I can't find anything on CPU usage.

[image]

Comment: If you have DBQL enabled, that would be a good place to start.  See if you can select from `dbc.dbqlogtbl` or `dbc.qrylog`.  This will give you usage metrics like - CPUTime, I/O, spool, etc.  There are several other DBQL tables that give your more info too, but this would be your first stop.  Just be careful, they'll probably be very big, so you should narrow down your query. https://docs.teradata.com/reader/B7Lgdw6r3719WUyiCSJcgw/BC8owdBbJGdQXIlV_aWrSA

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, I just attempted to SELECT FROM dbc.dbqlogtbl and dbc.qrylog but I do not have access to these tables.

Comment: Have to go to your DBAs then, which might be better anyhow. Interpreting those tables is not trivial.